# three integrals sum to a $_{3}F_{2}$ value

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

Let $K(x)$ and $E(x)$ denote complete elliptic integrals of the first and
second kind. Let
$$A=\frac{1024}{9\pi^{3}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}
\,\frac{t\left(  8t^{4}+8t^{2}-1\right)  E\left(  i\,t\right)  ^{2}}{\left(
2t^{2}+1\right)  ^{5}}dt,$$

$$B=\frac{-2048}{9\pi^{3}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}
\,\frac{t\left(  4t^{4}+3t^{2}-1\right)  E\left(  i\,t\right)  K\left(
i\,t\right)  }{\left(  2t^{2}+1\right)  ^{5}}dt,$$

$$C=\frac{1024}{9\pi^{3}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}
\,\frac{t\left(  2t^{4}+t^{2}-1\right)  K\left(  i\,t\right)  ^{2}}{\left(
2t^{2}+1\right)  ^{5}}dt.$$

Prove that $A+B+C=_{3}F_{2}\left(-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{3}{2};1,2;1\right)$.
If possible, find $A$, $B$ and $C$ separately as well.

This would solve an open problem in convex geometry (http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3468).  Thanks!

Comment: Important thing: here $it$ stands for the elliptic modulus or the elliptic parameter, i.e. are you adopting the standard notation or Mathematica's one?

Comment: I've adopted the standard notation.  Thus my $E(i\,t)$ is the same as Mathematica's EllipticE[-t^2]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will think about it.

Comment: Talking about page $8$ of your article: instead of performing an explicit integration with respect to $d\theta$, why not to expand the square root as a Taylor series, pull out the series, integrate the remaining part through Euler's Beta function, then compute the series? This should lead to a hypergeometric representation in a more direct way then trying to manage $A$, $B$, $C$ separately (which is difficult).

Answer (score 0):

**This is a long comment,** because I think another form for the integral might be useful, and it looks interesting.

I will use Mathematica notation for Elliptic integrals, because it's more convenient in this case. Let:

$$t^2=p$$

By adding all the integrals, and rearranging the terms in the denominator, we can write:

$$A+B+C=\frac{512}{9 \pi^3}(I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4)$$

Where:

$$I_1=2\int_0^\infty \frac{p^2 \left(2 E(-p)-K(-p) \right)^2}{(2p+1)^5}dp$$

$$I_2=\int_0^\infty \frac{p \left(3 E(-p)-K(-p) \right)^2}{(2p+1)^5}dp$$

$$I_3=-\int_0^\infty \frac{\left(E(-p)-K(-p) \right)^2}{(2p+1)^5}dp$$

$$I_4=-\int_0^\infty \frac{p E^2(-p)}{(2p+1)^5}dp$$

Mathematica gives at least $8$ correct digits when comparing the resulting numerical expression with the provided hypergeometric function.

If I have any more thoughts, I will extend this post.